# What HD projectors have a 80" screen at about 13 feet?

Tags: projector

We are trying to replace an older Optima projector, but we'd like to upgrade to something that can be used to show higher resolution, has more lumens, a longer lamp life, but will still work with our audio equipment.  We bought something and had to return it, because we couldn't get the display small enough in our room.

The wall area we have to use is 43" high, 70" wide, so about an 80" diagonal.  The projector itself is set at 12" 7" (152") away.  To get it any closer, we'd have to have it hanging above our heads.  And the room is designed with the ceiling angling down, so ceiling mount is out.

The audio equipment has ordinary analog input.  We have a blu-ray player (not yet used) with HDMI and digital audio output.  Ideally, the projector would have plugs for RCA phono-jacks.  In other words, we have a nice library with a wall, nice old speakers, and would like to upgrade so we can watch blu-ray without replacing everything and perhaps also having to move to a completely different space.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for the lens throw ratio. That number will tell you how big the size of the image is going to be. Also many projectors have zoom capabilities.
A lens with a 2.0 throw ratio means that for every unit you go away from the projecting surface, the size of the image will grow 2 times (simplest example, you won't find that specific throw distance). So 152"/ 70" gives you a throw ratio of around 2.17.